# Disabling Samsung battery management from putting my apps to sleep when the phone screen is turned off and running on the battery

Tags: applications, battery, sleep

I'm looking to disable Android's battery management.
On my Samsung S10 Plus running Android version 11 are several apps running in the background,
but they only run when the phone's USB port is connected to a charging source such as the mains adaptor or to my computer or when the screen is turned on regardless of being plugged in or running on the battery. The apps fall to sleep within a minute or two when the phone is running on the battery and the screen is turned off. All of these issues started after I upgraded to the current Android version on the S10+. Also this phone is not rooted. We also have older Samsung phones like the S9 and S8 running Android 10 without any app battery management issues.

I have done the following:
I wiped the cache partition.
I have the "Adaptive battery" setting under "More battery settings" turned off.
I have the "Put unused apps to sleep" setting under "Background usage limits" turned off.
I have added the apps to "Never sleeping apps" screen's list under "Background usage limits" turned off.

Despite doing all of the above, the current OS seems to be ignoring all of the settings I have set. Do any of you know of an app or any additional settings that will stop my apps from being put to sleep like that? This never happened when running Android version 9 and below.

All help will be appreciated.